# Tests randomly fails

Tags: c++, testing, do-while

I'm writing board game and I need following functionality: player rolls two dices, if he rolled doubles (same number on both dice), he gets to roll again, if he rolled doubles again, he goes to jail.

In my `Game` class it looks like that

```
void logic::Game::rollTheDice() {
    m_throwsInCurrentTurn++; 
    int firstThrow = m_firstDice.roll();
    int secondThrow = m_secondDice.roll();
    m_totalRollResult += firstThrow + secondThrow;
    if (firstThrow == secondThrow) m_doublesInCurrentTurn++;
}

std::string logic::Game::checkForDoubles() {
    std::string message;
        if (m_doublesInCurrentTurn == 0 && m_throwsInCurrentTurn == 1) {
            m_canThrow = false;
            m_canMove = true;           
        }

        if (m_doublesInCurrentTurn == 1 && m_throwsInCurrentTurn == 1) {
            message = "Doubles! Roll again.";           
            m_canThrow = true;
            m_canMove = false;
        }

        if (m_doublesInCurrentTurn == 1 && m_throwsInCurrentTurn == 2) {            
            m_canThrow = false;
            m_canMove = true;
        }

        if (m_doublesInCurrentTurn == 2 && m_throwsInCurrentTurn == 2) {
            message = "Doubles again! You are going to jail.";
            m_canThrow = false;
            m_canMove = false;
            getActivePlayer().lockInJail();
        }
        return message;
    }

void logic::Game::setInMotion(unsigned number) {
    m_players[m_activePlayer].startMoving(); 
    m_players[m_activePlayer].incrementPosition(number);
}
```

`m_canThrow` basicly enables or disables ability to click "Roll the Dice" button, `m_canMove` decides if player token can start moving, `m_players[m_activePlayer]` is `std::vector<Player>`, `startMoving()` does that,

```
void logic::Player::startMoving() {
    m_isMoving = true;
}
```

needed for token movement, so baiscly not relevant here.

Last function from `Game` class I need to show you is `reset()`, used mainly for testing purposes

```
void logic::Game::reset() {
    m_throwsInCurrentTurn = 0;
    m_doublesInCurrentTurn = 0;
    m_totalRollResult = 0;
}
```

Now finnaly Unit Test that sometimes goes wrong. Sometimes, I mean completely random, like 1 out of 10-20 times.

```
//first throw is double, second throw is not
TEST_F(GameTestSuite, shouldFinishAfterSecondRollAndMove) {
    auto game = m_sut.get();

    do {
        if (game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() == 2) game.reset();
        game.rollTheDice();
        game.checkForDoubles();
        if (game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() == 1 && game.getDoublesInCurrentTurn() == 1) {
            ASSERT_EQ(game.canThrow(), true);
            ASSERT_EQ(game.canMove(), false);           
        }
    } while (game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() != 2 && game.getDoublesInCurrentTurn() != 1);

    ASSERT_EQ(game.canThrow(), false);
    ASSERT_EQ(game.canMove(), true);

    game.setInMotion(game.getTotalRollResult());

    ASSERT_EQ(game.getActivePlayer().isMoving(), true);
    ASSERT_EQ(game.getActivePlayer().getPosition(), game.getTotalRollResult());
}
```

This line exactly, `ASSERT_EQ(game.canThrow(), false);` sometimes is equal `true` after `do-while` loop that should end once `m_canThrow` is set to `false`

Comment: This is the fundamental issue with random tests: when they fail, they fail randomly. Think about the only case where `m_canThrow` is `true`: `m_doublesInCurrentTurn == 1 && m_throwsInCurrentTurn == 1`, hence `m_throwsInCurrentTurn` is not equal to 2 (since it is equal to 1), hence the term `game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() != 2` = `true`, and `m_doublesInCurrentTurn` is equal to 1, hence the term `game.getDoublesInCurrentTurn() != 1` = `false`. `true && false` = `false`, hence loop is terminated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shouldn't:

```
} while (game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() != 2 && game.getDoublesInCurrentTurn() != 1);
```

be

```
} while (game.getThrowsInCurrentTurn() != 2 && game.getDoublesInCurrentTurn() <= 1);
```

You want to allow up to two turns but 0 or 1 doubles.